# unresolved import 'telegram.ext'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy haciendo un chatbot para telegram. Segui la documentacion, instale los elementos que se requeria y no hay errores en otro aspecto mas que al principio con el `from telegram.ext`

Ya busque en la misma documentacion donde tenia de referencia, busque en algunos otros foros pero hasta el momento no he encontrado una forma que me ayude. Desinstale todo pensando que a lo mejor fue algo que puse pero tampoco funciono

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: con estos datos no se puede reproducir el problema. Indica exactamente qué pasos seguiste. ¿Has instalado el [`python-telegram-bot`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot)?

Comment: si, lo instale
segui todo lo que estaba aqui: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-Your-first-Bot
y tambien aqui https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot

pense que hubo algun error y lo desinstale y lo volvi a instalar pero nada

Comment: acabo de seguir los pasos y me funcionó correctamente: hice `pip install python-telegram-bot` y luego abrí consola, donde `from telegram.ext import Updater` funcionó.

Comment: Y es que se me hace super curioso que me haya pasado eso si ha habia manejado un chatbot antes, nunca habia tenido ese problema, es mas, utilice uno que ya tenia funcionando al 100% y solo tenia que agregarle unos aspectos para que hiciera lo que yo necesitaba pero vi que me comenzo a marcar eso en el codigo y lo que hice fue hacer uno desde cero y me marcaba lo mismo. Descargue algunos ejemplos y lo mismo.
Termine desinstalando Python y volverlo a instalar pero ocurre lo mismo

Comment: Lo suyo sería: 1. Instala el python que quieras. 2. Crea un entorno virtual y actívalo. 3. Haz la instalación con pip. 4. Abre consola e intenta importar.

Comment: Cuando instalas algo con pip y luego al importar tienes el típico `ModulenotFoundError`, descartando errores tipográficos o instalación de paquete equivocado, casi siempre se debe a que simplemente has instalado en el intérprete o entorno virtual equivocado o intentas ejecutar el script en el que no es. en el script que te da el error elimina todo y coloca `import sys; print(sys.executable)`. Lo que te imprime es la ruta absoluta al intérprete. Copia la ruta y vete a una terminal y haz `ruta/al/interprete -m pip install  python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: No obstante, crear un nuevo entorno exclusivo para tu proyecto como plantea fedorqui es siempre buena idea. Sea como sea yo recomiendo usar siempre pip como módulo usando una ruta o referencia explícita al intérprete al que pertenece y en el que se va a instalar lo que sea. Usar pip como comando sin saber al intérprete al que apunta (lo que incluye los paquetes propios de algunas  distros en las que Python no suele tener instalado pip, sino que pip/pip3 es un paquete externo) causa muchos problemas de este tipo, en SO se repite mucho estos casos...